# Properties removed from Admin SDK Reports API

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I've been using the Admin SDK's Reports API to monitor G Suite license utilization (via GAM). It appears that around mid-June of this year, the relevant accounts properties were removed from the API results, causing all my license checks to fail.

If I diff the [documented API properties](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/customers-accounts) with what I actually get back, I find the following properties all missing:

```
apps_total_licenses
apps_used_licenses
authorized_apps
coordinate_total_licenses
gsuite_basic_total_licenses
gsuite_basic_used_licenses
gsuite_education_total_licenses
gsuite_education_used_licenses
gsuite_enterprise_total_licenses
gsuite_enterprise_used_licenses
gsuite_unlimited_total_licenses
gsuite_unlimited_used_licenses
num_archived_users
num_authorized_apps
num_users_used_quota_ge_50_lt_80percent
num_users_used_quota_ge_80percent
team_drive_used_quota_in_mb
vault_total_licenses
```

Is there an alternative for this information? Did something break?

EDIT: I've logged a report in Google's time machine: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117747908, if anyone else stumbles across this and is interested in following.

Comment: Have you tried reporting it to the [Admin SDK support](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/get-start/getting-started#api-resources)?

Comment: No. https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/support clearly states that technical assistance questions should be fielded through StackOverflow first, then escalated to Google.

Comment: It appears to have been silently fixed with no comments here or on the issue tracker.